# Application.Selection is returning the wrong Range

Tags: excel, vba

When I call a sub routine using a Userform, its dropping values into the wrong cells SOMETIMES.
Trying to identify if this is a bug, logical error, or some kind of user error I need to account for.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim selRng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Set selRng = Application.Selection
    Dim finalString As String

        finalString = ComboBox1.Value & "(" & TextBox1.Value & ")"


        For Each cel In selRng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            cel.Value = finalString
        Next cel

End Sub
```

Here is my sample code to get a Combobox value and drop it into the selected cell range.

It works great except for two cases that I know of:

- There is a cell that is currently copied to clipboard and a cell is selected.
- When I first open the excel file and try to run this command button

What happens is it will place the value in each cell in the first row and the first column down until the first non-null value.

My goal is for it to go to my Selected cell range, which it does under the right conditions.

I am not sure how the invocation of Application.Selection works exactly.

Is this a problem with VBA/Excel or is this because I am calling specialCells on top of my range?

Thank you,

Comment: I don't think `SpecialCells` plays well with a single cell.

Comment: @BigBen I added an if Case for single cell selections and so far so good. Thank you for the heads up on this.

Answer (score 1):

I [don't believe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215151/on-the-selection-of-a-single-cell) `SpecialCells` plays well with a single cell. Try the following:

```
If selRng.CountLarge > 1 Then
    Set selRng = selRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End If
    
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In selRng
    cel.Value = finalString
Next cel
```